# Python Time Series using Prophet

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, facebook-prophet

Using Prophet FB in Python, I have build Time Series model. I have performed cross validation and use performance_metrics to evaluate the Time Series model.

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
from fbprophet.diagnostics import cross_validation, performance_metrics

my_df # dataframe contains 2 columns: date 'yyyy-mm-dd' and integer value

model = Prophet() #Bayesian 
model.fit(my_df)

df_cv = cross_validation(model,  
                         horizon = '359 days',
                         initial='4 days')
# df_cv # outputs dataframe with columns: ds, yhat, yhat_lower, yhat_upper, y, cutoff
df_p = performance_metrics(df_cv)
df_p.head() # gives dataframe output below
```

[image]

I am trying to evaluate if this TS model did well or not. As far as I have understood, RMSE value have to be low as possible. However, I do not know if the results above are considered low or high?

Comment: one thing that you're doing wrong is using a too low initial value. How big is your data? I would use the initial values as 80% of the available data, then you can play with the other parameters, horizon and period.